# Oracle query’s required

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracles

The variables $a,b,c \in \{0,1\}$, thus $a^k, b^k, c^k \in \{0,1\}$

I want to pass a query to an oracle that returns the coefficients of each term $(1,a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc)$ in the expansion of products such as this one $(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)(b-bc)$. There could be more variables and more brackets to expand.

Do I require a single FP query to do this or something more?

---

edit:

Input: $(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)$

Expand: $a b^2 c - a b^2 - a b c + 2 a b - a + b c - b + 1$

Apply property of idempotence:  $a b c - a b - a b c + 2 a b - a + b c - b + 1$

Simplify: $1 - a - b + ab +bc$

Extract coefficients: \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ a & -1 \\ b & -1 \\ c & 0 \\ ab & 1 \\ ac & 0 \\ bc & 1 \\ abc & 0 \end{matrix}

Question: What is the 'weakest' oracle capable of extracting the coefficients above from the input?

Comment: In other words, you’re asking whether it’s possible to calculate individual coefficients in polynomial time.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you specify separately: what is the problem you are trying to solve?  (what is the input, and what is the desired output?)  what function does the oracle implement?  (what is the input to the oracle, and what is the output?)  What's an FP query?  When you say "do this", what is the "this"?  Can you [edit] your question to specify the problem more systematically?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @D.W. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If it is I would love to know!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Has my edit helped?

Comment: Yes, I now understand the problem. Please also make clear what the input could look like. Moreover, note that there could be many coefficients, so if you want an answer in polytime, you can only expect to get a single coefficient (more generally, polynomially many coefficients).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the input could be any Boolean formula written in elementary algebra. Using the transformation $\text{Not}(A) = 1-A$ and $A\wedge B = AB$.

There are $2^n$ coefficients. If it can be shown to be impossible to retrieve these coefficients in polynomial time then I think it follows that P $\neq$ #P

Comment: The best you can hope for, then, is showing that the problem is NP-hard. In any case, I suggest updating (rather than editing) your post to reflect this information. There's no reason to have part of your post marked as "Edit".

Comment: Perhaps you should also mention your [possibly related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118201/algorithm-for-idempotent-algebra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is #P-hard. Indeed, given a #SAT instance with variables $x_i$ and clauses $C_j$, let $\kappa_{i,b}$ be the product of the clauses $C_j$ satisfied by the truth assignment $x_i=b$, and consider
$$ P = \prod_i (\kappa_{i,0} + \kappa_{i,1}). $$
The coefficient of $\prod_j C_j$ in $P$ is the number of satisfying assignments.

In the other direction, the special case where the input formula is $\Pi\Sigma\Pi$ (that is, the product of polynomials) is #P-complete. Suppose that we are interested in the coefficient of some monomial $m$ in $\prod_k P_k$, where the $P_k$ are polynomials. Substitute zero in all variables not appearing in $m$. Now guess one term from each $P_k$, and accept if the terms together cover $m$.